# angular 6 shared module not work with other modules

Tags: angular, angular6

please check my below shared module file.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import {SharedPipesModule} from '../../shared/pipes/shared-pipes.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SharedPipesModule,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    SharedPipesModule,
  ]
})

export class SharedModule { }
```

i import custom pipe file as a 'SharedPipesModule'.  now i am trying to access sharedmodule file for a another component. therefor i imported shared file. check below code.

```
    import { NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { GlHeaderRoutModule } from './gl-header-rout.module';
import { PageHeaderModule } from './../../shared';
import { GlHeaderComponent} from './gl-header.component';
import {MatButtonModule, MatSort, MatPaginator, MatCardModule , MatTable, MatTableModule, MatSortable, MatTableDataSource, MatIconModule, MatSortModule, MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material';
import {MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import {SharedModule} from '../../shared/org-sort/shared-module.module';
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, GlHeaderRoutModule, PageHeaderModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    NgbModule, FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatIconModule, MatTableModule,
    MatSortModule, MatCardModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule, MatPaginatorModule, SharedModule,
    MatExpansionModule],
  declarations: [GlHeaderComponent]
})
export class GlHeaderModule { }
```

is this correct ??

when i run project error occurred,

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'unique' could not be found ("> 
      --Select--
       ]bank of sortBy('orgName') | unique">{{bank.orgName}}

SharedPipesModule code,

```
import { NgModule, Pipe, Injectable, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

@Injectable()
@Pipe({
  name: 'unique',
  pure: false
})

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: []
})

export class SharedPipesModule implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any): any {
      if (value !== undefined && value !== null) {
          return _.uniqBy(value, 'orgName');
      }
      return value;
  }
}
```

Comment: of course, it's correct. what is the actual problem you are facing?

Comment: error is ,

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'unique' could not be found ("> 
      <option value="undefined" disabled="true">--Select--</option>
       <option *ngFor="let [ERROR ->]bank of sortBy('orgName') | unique">{{bank.orgName}}</option> 
    </select>

Comment: can you share the code of `SharedPipesModule`?

Comment: please check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the @NgModule decorator, just create a pipe as follows:

```
import { Pipe, Injectable, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

@Injectable()
@Pipe({
  name: 'unique',
  pure: false
})



export class SharedPipes implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any): any {
      if (value !== undefined && value !== null) {
          return _.uniqBy(value, 'orgName');
      }
      return value;
  }
}
```

In your sharedModule, declare the pipe and export it as follows:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import {SharedPipes} from '../../shared/pipes/shared-pipes.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SharedPipes,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    SharedPipes,
  ]
})

export class SharedModule { }
```

Comment: import {SharedPipes} from '../../shared/pipes/shared-pipes.module';   or 

import {SharedPipesModule} from '../../shared/pipes/shared-pipes.module'; ?

Comment: it's based on your class name, in the above code the class name is `export class SharedPipes implements PipeTransform`

Answer (score 2):

Try this at **SharedPipesModule**:

```
@NgModule({       
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [SharedPipesModule], // Adding SharedPipesModule to declarations
    exports: [SharedPipesModule], // Adding SharedPipesModule to exports
})
```

Comment: Can you share any screenshot please